# Rust type parameter with HRTB

Tags: rust

I have the following type

```rust
struct Test<Args> {
  // ...
  phantom: PhantomData<Args>,
}
```

that needs to store, alongside it's contents, a type parameter for determining arguments to a function to be passed on later.

I use it as follows:

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]
impl<Args> Test<Args> {
    fn update<F>(&mut self, args: Args, f: F)
    where
         F: FnOnce<Args>
    {
       //...
       let value = f.call_once(args);
       // ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use it for borrowed values. I would need to be able to do something like

```
type MyTest = Test<for<'a> (&'a u32, &'a u32)>;
let mut t: MyTest = ...;
t.update((&5, &8), |lhs, rhs| lhs + rhs);
```

But `Test<for<'a> (&'a u32, &'a u32)>` is not valid syntax.

My workaround currently is to modify `Test` to instead take in an `fn` type and then restrict it alongside another type at the call site as follows:

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]
struct Test<F> {
  // ...
  phantom: PhantomData<F>,
}

impl<F> Test<F> {
    fn update<Args, F2>(&mut self, args: Args, f: F2)
    where
         F: FnOnce<Args>,
         F2: FnOnce<Args>,
    {
       //...
       let value = f.call_once(args);
       // ...
    }
}

type MyTest = Test<for<'a> fn(&'a u32, &'a u32)>;
let mut t: MyTest = ...;
t.update((&5, &8), |lhs, rhs| lhs + rhs);
```

But this is relatively ugly and requires changing the public interface. I'm also not sure if there's any issues with `fn` being contra-variant in it's arguments.

**Is there any better way to achieve this while keeping the original signature (or close to it)?**

I don't want to use the call-site `F` itself in the type generics, as I need it to be generic in the method and not the type, as it can be a closure with borrowed values while the type may be static.

Answer (score 0):

The way to express the `MyTest` type alias is like so:

```
type MyTest<'a> = Test<(&'a u32, &'a u32)>;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need `MyTest` to work for every lifetime `'a`, not for some specific lifetime `'a`, like in the workaround, so this doesn't work

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I see, you want `Test` to be typed that it'll accept `&T` arguments that are generic over their lifetimes since they'll be deduced at the `update()` call-site. Unfortunately, I don't think Rust supports this use-case; your attempted syntax would probably be the way to do it if it was.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll be using `&String` instead of `&u32` as now `&5` is promoted to `&'static u32` which doesn't have the problem since it's `'static`.)

Ideally `Args` would actually be a HRT (Higher rank type) of type `'a -> ty` (i.e. it receives a lifetime and outputs a type).

Unfortunately this isn't possible in rust currently. However, we can use a workaround with a trait, we can define a `WithLifetime` trait that functions just like a `HRT`:

```rust
trait WithLifetime {
    type Output<'a>: Tuple;
}
```

(The `: Tuple` requirement is because `Fn<Args>` now requires `Args: Tuple`).

We can them implement it on a new type to serve as the HRT.

```
struct BorrowedString;

impl WithLifetime for BorrowedString {
    type Output<'a> = (&'a String, &'a String);
}
```

(Note: We could also implement it for `(&'static String,  &'static String)` and use it later on, but this is easier to understand)

After this we can make `update` use `WithLifetime`:

```rust
impl<Args: WithLifetime> Test<Args> {
    fn update<'a, F>(&mut self, args: Args::Output<'a>, f: F)
    where
         F: FnOnce<Args::Output<'a>>
    {
       //...
       let value = f.call_once(args);
       // ...
    }
}
```

Now we can call `update` twice with temporaries without worrying about the lifetime of the temporaries:

```rust
type MyTest = Test<BorrowedString>;
let mut t = ...;
t.update((&"a".to_owned(), &"b".to_owned()), |lhs, rhs| lhs.clone() + rhs);
t.update((&"c".to_owned(), &"d".to_owned()), |lhs, rhs| lhs.clone() + rhs);
```

Should be noted that for `(&String, &String)` we can simply use a single `'a` lifetime, since `&T` is covariant, so any `(&'a T, &'b T)` can be coerced into a `(&'c T, &'c T)`, where `'a: 'c` and `'b: 'c` (i.e. `'c` is shorter or equal than both `'a` and `'b`).

This is not the case for other types, so `WithLifetime` isn't enough. You might also want to use a type / const generic within your HRT. The solution is to modify `WithLifetime::Output` to something like `type Output<'l0, 'l1, 'l2, ..., T1, T2, T3, ..., , G1, const V1: G1, G2, const V2: G2>` (for the max number of lifetimes / types / const generics you might need. Also note that `G1, const V1: G1` isn't currently allowed, so you might define `const V1_usize: usize, const V1_u32: u32` ... etc if you really need.)

Comment: This also changes the interface, so it is not clear what is the advantage over the solution in your question. IMO this is just more clunky.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman For non-generic types, this solution keeps the same interface (provided you implement `WithLifetime` as the identity HRT for those types) and instead only requires special handling for the types that didn't work before. I will admit `WithLifetime` is really clunky, especially if you need to handle several generics, but since you only need to use it in special cases, I believe it's worth the complexity.